# HAproxy and Atmosphere / Vaadin Push: Connection remotely closed

Tags: vaadin, haproxy, atmosphere

Since we enabled Push in our Vaadin application, we get tons of exceptions of the following type:

```
2015-08-10 14:32:06,934 ERROR [Atmosphere-Shared-AsyncOp-14341] com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler
Exception in push connection java.io.IOException: Connection remotely closed for c84be8fd-2168-4759-990f-b36bbc4f2712
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:229)
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:219)
at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:47)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$2.write(AtmosphereResponse.java:552)
at org.atmosphere.handler.AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.java:148)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:51)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.invokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1074)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.prepareInvokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1094)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:899)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$3.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:520)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745),
Exception in push connection
```

We also have performance issues since push is enabled. For some users the app often results in non-answering UIs and endless loading indicators.

Our setup is:
Vaadin 7.5.0, Automatic push mode (websockets)
Jetty 9
HAProxy with following config (only the relevant fragments):

```
defaults
log global
mode http
option httplog
option dontlognull
option forwardfor
option http-server-close
#for jetty, tomcat...
option http-pretend-keepalive

retries 3
option redispatch

maxconn 4000
timeout connect 5s
timeout client 600s
timeout server 600s
timeout client-fin 60s
timeout tunnel 3600s
```

## Questions:

1. Is it a critical one / can it result in a not responding application??
2. What are we doing wrong in our HAProxy config?

Comment: I noticed [this ticket # 17,075](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/17075) for upcoming 7.6 fixing a problem with long-polling and certain proxies. I've no idea if this is your issue. But you might want to use the client-side monitor to see which mode of Push is being used.

Comment: @Basil: Normally, a websocket push connection is established